# how to pass node's label from tcl to .cc

Tags: tcl, ns2

I'm working on NS-2.35
I write below instruction in **TCL** to assign a label to specific nodes:

```
$ns_ at 0 "$sink($i) label SuperNode" ;
```

now i need to use this **label** in **.CC**

what should i do?

Comment: I think you need to explain a bit more about why this isn't working for you…

Comment: I just want to use this label in c++ codes to define some conditions(if...else...). I have no idea how can i  use the label which i define in tcl codes (SuperNode) in C++ codes